# Find longest lines from a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++14

This is a challenge question from [codeeval.com](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/2/):

> Write a program which reads a file and prints to stdout the specified
>   number of the longest lines that are sorted based on their length in
>   descending order. Input sample:
>
> Your program should accept a path to a file as its first argument. The
>   file contains multiple lines. The first line indicates the number of
>   lines you should output, the other lines are of different length and
>   are presented randomly. You may assume that the input file is
>   formatted correctly and the number in the first line is a valid
>   positive integer.
>
> **For Example:**
>
> ```
> 2 
> Hello World
> CodeEval 
> Quick Fox
> A
> San Francisco
> ```
>
> **Output sample:**
>
> Print out the longest lines limited by specified number and sorted by
>   their length in descending order.
>
> **For example:**
>
> ```
> San Francisco 
> Hello World
> ```

Please let me know how I can improve this implementation.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<chrono>

class fixed_hash{
public:
        fixed_hash( int pSize )
        {
            size = pSize;
        }
        void push( std::string & record )
        {

            if( hash_table.size() < size )
            {
                hash_table.emplace( std::make_pair( record.size(), record ) );
            }
            else if( record.size() > hash_table.rbegin()->second.size() )
            {
                hash_table.erase( hash_table.begin() );
                hash_table.emplace( std::make_pair( record.size(), record ) );
            }
        }
        void print()
        {
            auto end = std::rend(hash_table);
            for( auto it = std::rbegin( hash_table ); it != end ; ++it )
            {
                std::cout << it->second << "\n";
            }
        }

 private:
        std::map<int,std::string> hash_table;
        int size;
};

void readInputFile( std::string fileName )
{
    std::ifstream infile( fileName );
    std::string record;
    int output_nbr = 0;
    infile >> output_nbr;
    fixed_hash output_string_list( output_nbr );
    while( std::getline( infile, record ) )
    {
        output_string_list.push( record );
    }

    output_string_list.print();
    infile.close();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        std::cout << "Error: input file is missing " << "\n";
        exit( 0 );
    }

    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );
    readInputFile( argv[ 1 ]);

    auto end      = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
    std::cout<< duration.count() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: C++ has a built in heap type: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/

Comment: Also note that your `hash_table` is not a hash-table in the strict meaning of the word. `std::map` is *a binary search tree*. If you really care about using a true hash-table, then the correct container would be [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: @glampert - The name is a misnomer. Steephen is very much taking advantage of the fact that a `std::map` is ordered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug:

```
else if( record.size() > hash_table.rbegin()->second.size() )
```

As implemented, insertion stops once your program encounters the longest line in the file.

For example, suppose the input contains:

> ```
> 2
> abcdefghijklmop
> a
> ab
> abc
> abcd
> ```

Your program will output:

> ```
> abcdefghijklmop
> a
> ```

The fix is simple: Change `rbegin` to `begin`.

---

Another potential issue is your use of a `std::map` as opposed to some other container. Your concept is fine, but not necessarily for "I'm the best hacker!" type sites that place strong emphasis on execution time. A vector-based solution could be faster. With the red-black tree-based hash, search, insertion, and delete are \$O(log n)\$ (but with large constants). With a vector-based solution, search would be \$O(log n)\$ (but potentially much faster than a red-black search), deleting the tail is \$O(1)\$ (which is a big win), but insertion is \$O(n)\$ (which is of course a big loss). However, for small enough values of *n*, a fast \$O(n)\$ algorithm can and will beat a slow \$O(log n)\$ algorithm.

One last remark: Rather than your `void print()` member, a stream insertion operator would be more C++-like:

```cpp
class fixed_hash
{
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const fixed_hash& hash);
    ...
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const fixed_hash& hash)
{
    auto end = std::rend(hash.hash_table);
    for( auto it = std::rbegin(hash.hash_table); it != end ; ++it )
    {
        os << it->second << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Good catch on spotting the bug! Interesting that our reviews are largely complementary.  It's yet more evidence that multiple reviews are more useful than any single one.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code, but with the caveat that "improve" could mean one of several things.  In this review, I'm mostly going to comment on things that will make the code more readable, and not necessarily yield performance improvements.

### Use better naming

The name `readInputFile` is a bit misleading, since it does much more than simply reading -- all of the processing, including output, is done there.  Also, I tend to prefer CamelCase for class names, so I'd be inclined to name the class something else, perhaps `FixedHash`, although I'm not very fond of that name either.

### Use `std::size_t` instead of `int`

A more appropriate type for your `size` in `fixed_hash` would be `std::size_t` instead of `int`.

### Consider using a `multiset` instead

One could easily argue it either way, but I'd be inclined to use a `std::multiset` instead of a `std::map`.  Your current code is more efficient in that it uses less memory and is probably faster, but an alternative would be to use a more-or-less plain `multiset`:

```
template <class T>
struct longer {
    bool operator()(const T &left, const T &right) const {
        return right.size() < left.size();
    }
};
std::multiset<std::string, longer<std::string>> lines;
```

Printing would then be:

```
for (auto line = lines.cbegin(); count && line != lines.cend(); ++line, --count) {
    std::cout << *line << std::endl;
}
```

If needed, you could adapt the multiset as you have for the map.  It seems to me that the code might be slightly simpler.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

Comment: I have to disagree. Not enough to downvote, but I disagree. (1) Better naming. Many people have come to the realization that CamelCaseWasABigUnreadableMistake. (2) `size_t` vs `int`. This is a problem on machines using an OS from Redmond. On other machines, are you going to find text files that are 2 billion lines long, lines that are 2 billion characters long? The answer is almost always no. (3) `multiset` vs `set`. This depends on ones interpretation of a key vague point in the challenge, how to treat lines of the same length. (4) Never omit `return 0`! Adding that shortcut was a travesty.

Comment: @DavidHammen: regarding CamelCase - it's a personal preference, which is why I stated it as such and not as a recommendation.  Better, more descriptive naming is still advisable, regardless of the form it's expressed. For `size_t` vs. `int` -- it's a signed/unsigned rather than an OS-specific thing.  I use Linux and gcc here; gcc correctly warns about a sign mismatch in the comparison.  IMHO, it's best to address the potential problem during construction rather than have it fail in the distant future when someone *does* try it on 2 billion lines.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Have to disagree with all your points. 1) Most => not true. There are multiple arguments on all fronts. 2) Not true. MS machines use size_t fine. 3) What. 4) Omitting `return 0` in main is pretty standard when there is no chance the application can fail (it is a way of documenting that the application does not fail).

Answer (score 5):

You may consider using `std::multimap` since there may be strings of equal length in the input. For example (C++11), change your input stream accordingly or use `freopen` with this code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    multimap <size_t, string, greater<size_t>> map;
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)) 
        map.emplace(line.length(), line);
    for (auto i = map.begin(); i != map.end() && n--; ++i)
        cout << i->second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See it working [here](http://ideone.com/6Ien7p).

---

C++11 is not present on codeeval.com. A C++03 compatible version would look like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    multimap <size_t, string, greater<size_t> > map;
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)) 
        map.insert(make_pair(line.length(), line));
    for (multimap<size_t, string>::iterator i = map.begin(); i != map.end() && n--; ++i)
        cout << i->second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all above answers, here are a few things that may improve your existing code:

In the `push` member function, it's not necessary to do the comparing and deleting and its algorithm there; it seems odd. It's better to make it for inserting a new elements that's quite regular, especially when `std::map` has template parameter comparators made for that purpose and the compare expression by default is `std::less<T>`. You can create your compare expression or use `std::greater<T>` which is defined in the `<functional>` header file.

```
std::map<std::size_t ,std::string, std::greater<int>> hash_table;
```

and `push` member function will be like this

```
    void push( std::string & record )
    {
        hash_table.emplace( std::make_pair( record.size(), record ) );
    }
```

In the `print` member function, try not use `std::begin()` `std::end()`. That would be really unnecessary for STL containers. It already has its own `begin()` and `end()`.

```
    void print()
    {
        for( auto it = hash_table.begin(); it != hash_table.end() && size; ++it , --size )
        {
            std::cout << it->second <<"\n";
        }
    }
```

My suggestion is to pick the right container for this question. It's known that `std::vector` is a better choice for small data sizes and best for iterating data, but it has limitations in lookup, unlike `std::map`. This example really is a perfect reason to go with `std::vector` over `std::map`, especially because it asked for longer lines in a text file only.

My opinion is to create `std::vector<std::string>` and once all data is stored in the vector, it can be sorted and printed easily by using what STL offers to us as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {       
        vec.push_back(line);
    }
    std::size_t n = atoi(vec.begin()->c_str());
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::string &left, const std::string &right){ return right.size() < left.size(); });
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + n, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following corrections are implemented:

1. Reported bug is fixed
2. Instead of `std::map<>` using `std::multi_map<>`
3. Using `size_t` instead of wrong use of `int` as a type

//

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<chrono>

class fixed_hash{
public:
        fixed_hash( std::size_t pSize )
        {
            size = pSize;
        }
        void push( std::string & record )
        {

            if( hash_table.size() < size )
            {
                hash_table.emplace( std::make_pair( record.size(), record ) );
            }
            else if( record.size() > hash_table.begin()->second.size() )
            {
                hash_table.erase( hash_table.begin() );
                hash_table.emplace( std::make_pair( record.size(), record ) );
            }
        }
        void print()
        {
            auto end = std::rend(hash_table);            
            for( auto it = std::rbegin( hash_table ); it != end ; ++it )            
            {
                std::cout << it->second << "\n";
            }
        }

 private:
        std::multimap<int,std::string> hash_table;
        std::size_t size;
};

void readInputFile( std::string fileName )
{
    std::ifstream infile( fileName );
    std::string record;
    int output_nbr = 0;
    infile >> output_nbr;
    fixed_hash output_string_list( output_nbr );
    while( std::getline( infile, record ) )
    {
        output_string_list.push( record );
    }

    output_string_list.print();
    infile.close();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if( argc < 2 )
    {
        std::cout << "Error: input file is missing " << "\n";
        exit( 0 );
    }

    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );
    readInputFile( argv[ 1 ]);

    auto end      = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start);
    std::cout<< duration.count() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```